# Having Problems getting a Grid View to select a row in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, shopping-cart

I've been working on this problem for a few days now.

Background: I have a shopping cart set up and it is stored in the session. I am pulling it out of session and binding it to a Grid View. I want users to be able to change the quantity of an item. I am running into several problems and this one is just not ironing itself out.

I have a button in each row with the Command Name "Select". When you click that button it brings up a Modal Pop Up window with a text box.

However when I click the button the SelectedValue is -1 and it throws an Out of Range exception.

It should be the ProductId of the item. the DataKey Name is the Product ID and when I show the product ID in the grid view it comes up as the correct non -1 ID.

```
 protected void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<int, ShoppingCartItem> cart = (Dictionary<int, ShoppingCartItem>)Session["Cart"];


    cart[(int)gvCart0.SelectedValue].Quantity = int.Parse(tbQuantity.Text);
    gvCart0.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**::please change the `CommandName` of your button to `"selectCart"`

Set the command argument property for your button :

**.aspx**

```
CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'
```

**.cs**

```
 protected void gvCart0_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            if (e.CommandName == "selectCart")
            {

                Dictionary<int, ShoppingCartItem> cart = (Dictionary<int, ShoppingCartItem>)Session["Cart"];
                cart[index].Quantity = int.Parse(tbQuantity.Text);

            }

            gvCart0.DataBind();

        }

        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            string message = ee.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: At first this didn't make a lot of sense. So let me make sure I understand it now.

Comment: Apparently you can't edit after 5 minutes. Weird O_o.
Here is the rest of that comment.
Am I creating a custom Command Name, and grabbing the index of the row I clicked in the aspx code you added?
My only question is that will the index variable you declared hold the product ID of the product in that row i.e. 35 or will it hold the row number i.e. 1?

Comment: I'm not even getting to the event handler that was created at all.

Comment: hmmm,`index` hold the row index not the product id , if you wanna to get the product id then you can store it in the `DataKeyNames` or even in a hidden field then get them easily.
like the following :
in the same event 
`int productId = int.Parse(gvCart0.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString())`

Comment: I'm still not even getting to the event handler. I've set it to the GV RowCommand event, and I've even tried setting it to the actual button itself but the GridViewCommandEventArgs weren't right and EventArgs didn't have the correct properties. My last test was to not set the event handler to any event at all and I still wasn't hitting it.

Comment: `GV RowCommand` is an event for the grid view not the button in the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

For RowEditing you have to do something like this on the RowEditing event to set the EditIndex,

```
protected void grid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}
```

You may need to do the same with the OnSelectedIndexChanging event.

Answer (score 0):

At first on ItemCommand  get the ProductId and store it in a View-State and after that on the ButtonClick Event do the corresponding thing you want to do by getting the ProductId from the View-State and don't forget to set the Data-Source to Grid-View as you are modifying the collection.